# Unable to link Apple ID with User Account in Lion 10.7.3

Tags: icloud, apple-id, system-settings

I'm desperately trying to link my user account with my Apple ID. After entering my ID and password a yellow warning sign appears in System Preferences beside the Set Apple ID button and the console shows the following error message:

2/8/12 10:07:02.936 PM System Preferences: _CSAddAppleIDAccountUsingCompletionBlock failed with -100

Any hints for me?

Comment: Are you trying to set up using your Apple ID to reset your Mac OS X lion account password? As indicated here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4798 <--"OS X Lion: Apple ID can be used to reset your user account password"

Comment: MrDaniel, no that's not my problem. I'm trying to configure the iCloud service, which is not possible. It may have something todo with keys missing in the keychain and I'm trying to sort out things. First of all it thought it might be a good idea to start with this on, as i found a console log entry.

Answer (score 1):

Hiho,

again I solved my own problem... error was related to some weirdo ACL problem of the keychain directory/files in ~/Library/Keychains . I got the hint from console showing

"*ERROR:password_store_mac.cc(263)] Keychain data load failed: 100013*"

when starting Chrome and this error ID is related to permissions.

> Chmod -RN

did the trick. Takeaway: Don't use finder to manipulate permissions. ;-)

Cheers
Roland